# Moon base, magnetic trap, and spider-like aliens in space

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book around 95-97, and I'm sure it was older than that.

It was sci fi, the main character was a male who got vertigo while descending to the moon, and met a girl at the moon base. She had a fuzzy little pet.

Later on the heroes become stuck in a magnetic trap, owned by spider like aliens that the hero ponders about because man had evolved in the warm ocean, but these creatures had evolved in cold space.

That's all I remember.

Comment: Did you create a second account to edit this question?

Comment: I've rolled back the edit from what appears to be a new account used by the same person. If you've lost your account information, please go through the [account recovery process](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20528/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-account). Also, see this [relevant meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6816/suggested-edits-by-users-probably-trying-to-edit-their-own-post-from-a-new-accou).

Comment: "Funny thing is that when I saw the film Gentleman Bronco's and in the opening credits they showed the book cover of "Have Space Suit Will Travel" the characters represented exactly what I had been looking for! But after reading a plot summary, that book is NOTHING like what I remember of this lost favorite."  **WHICH** "Have Space Suit Will Travel" cover was that? Was it one of [these](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?1811)?

Comment: Yes towards the bottom, a girl is holding the suit and male character has a small fuzzy pet near him.

-Travis Christian, no when I finished registering my account it took away my name and used my username.

Comment: Were the 'fuzzy pets' actually telepaths that were used for FTL communications?  I have a vague recollection of reading something like this in the 70s.

Answer (score 6):

[Trapped In Space](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1069302) by Jack Williamson

Jeff Stone goes to the lunar base to join an expedition to the star Topaz. There he meets the girl Lupe Flor, after he rescues her dog sized telepathic alien companion Buzz Dozen Dozen.

At Topaz their starship is trapped by an electrified metal Web spun between asteroids by spider like aliens who evolved and live in vacuum.

Things look grim for our heroes until Jeff encounters a spider alien during a space walk and they save each other's lives

Comment: Thanks for taking this Winchell, btw. LOVE your website! The best on the web!